# java random number bound by a variable

Tags: java, random, integer

I've got two Integer variables that are generated randomly

```
int scoreWon = random1.nextInt(20);
int scoreLost = random1.nextInt();
```

What I want to do is , bound the `scoreLost` value by `scoreWon` so the generated number will always be less than the value generated by `scoreWon`.

Is this way possible ?

```
int scoreWon = random1.nextInt(20);
int scoreLost = random1.nextInt(scoreWon);
```

or please help me out

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Just try it. The int parameter for nextInt() is the upper bound (exclusively) for the new random integer value (the lower bound is 0, inclusively).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's probably the best approach. The Random.nextInt(int bound) method returns a number from **0** to **bound-1** (bound is *exclusive*) as described here:

[Random.nextInt documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--)

Example: Random.nextInt(100) would be *0...99*

In your context:

```java
Random random = new Random();
int scoreWon = random.nextInt(20); //0...19
int scoreLost = random.nextInt(scoreWon); //0...18
```